# Django login required twice

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm making a webpage where I login and add people to an address book. Once I login and click on the "add address" button, I'm redirected back to the login page with the following url:

```
http://localhost:8000/xcard/login/?next=/xcard/add_address/
```

If I login again I can get to account page, address book, and then add_address book page without being caught in the login loop. I can logout and login and add addresses without relogin in twice. But the first time I ever login I have to do it twice. Not sure if it's a problem with the login or the add address code.

Views.py

```
class LoginView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        ''' if user is authenticated '''
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, 'xcard/account.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'xcard/login.html')

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        state = "The email or password is incorrect"

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/xcard/account/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'xcard/login.html', {'state':state})

class AddAddressView(View): 

    def get(self,request):
        address_form = AddressForm()
        friend_form = FriendForm()

        return render(request, 'xcard/add_address.html', {'friend_form':friend_form, 'address_form':address_form})

    def post(self,request):
        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        friend_form = FriendForm(request.POST)

        if address_form.is_valid() and friend_form.is_valid():
            new_address = address_form.save()
            new_friend = friend_form.save(commit=False)
            new_friend.address = new_address
            new_friend.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/xcard/address_book')
        else:
            return render(request, 'xcard/add_address.html', {'state' : "Failed", 'friend_form':friend_form, 'address_form':address_form})
```

Templates:
address_book.html

```
{% include "xcard/header.html" %}
{% block main %}

<div class="container">
<h3 class="text-info"><u>Your Account</u></h3>

<a href="/xcard/add_address/" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Add</a>
<a href="/xcard/import_address/" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Import</a>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Templates:
login.html

```
{% extends "xcard/base.html" %}
{% block main %}

<div class="container">
<div class="row space">
    <p class="text-center lead text-warning">
    Login page</p>
    <p class="text-center text-info">Trusted worldwide!</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span offset4"> 
        <form class="well" action="/xcard/login/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="lead">Sign In</p>

            <fieldset class="login_page">
                <p class="text-error"><strong>{{ state }}</strong></p>
                <label class="control-label" for ="inputIcon">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="span3" id="ernainputIcon" required name="username" placeholder="Username...."/><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <label>Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" class="span3" id="inputIcon" required name="password" placeholder="Password...."/><br/><br/><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
                Not a user?
                <a href="/xcard/registration/">Sign up</a>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

I just found this in my urls.py

```
url(r'^add_address/$', login_required(AddAddressView.as_view(), login_url='/xcard/login/')),
```

Maybe this is causing the problem? But why doesn't it register that I'm already logged in?

Comment: first in `AddAddressView` function update line `return render(request, 'xcard/add_address.html', {'friend_form':friend_form, 'address_form':address_form})`

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a typo when writing up my question. Thx.

Comment: Can you correct your indentation? You have code in your `LoginView` that should be indented. Is that how it actually is in your source?

Comment: Fixed the indentation. The source was correct before.

Comment: @TK Have you found a solution or the cause of this problem yet?

Comment: @Arsham I had the same problem. In my case it was because I did `HttpResponseRedirect("http://www.domain.tld/secured")` and this page checks by `request.user.is_authenticated()` if you are logged in or not. In the last case it would send the requestor back to the login page. I change this absolut URL to an relative `HttpResponseRedirect("/secured")` and now it works. Maybe this is helpful to someone :)

Answer (score 0):

first do the correction in AddAddressView function. update line

```
return render(request, 'xcard/add_address.html', {'friend_form':friend_form, 'address_form':address_form})
```

it will work

Comment: Still has same problem. On a new db I need to login twice.

Comment: I am not sure but you can check the condition which is written `if user is not None:` in `LoginView` class, either this condition is false that's why it is returning to login or you have to go through step by step with function and print all the value and check condition.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution - logout before you try to authenticate.

This issue happened to me when users were logging in and logging back in with a different username.

```
import django.contrib.auth as djangoAuth
djangoAuth.logout(request)  # logout
user = djangoAuth.authenticate(username=username, password=password) # login
```